# When I compile this why doesn't it print anything?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printing, initialization

1.Why does this not print anything, also does this code make sense? I'm new to java so I'm not exactly sure.

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import scanner so user can input

class arrays
{
    public static void main(String[] param)
    {
        arrays();
        System.exit(0);
    }//end main method

    public static int arrays() //array method 
    {
        int information = 0; // keeping a variable count
        String[] animals = new String[5]; //array to store 5 animals

        animals[0] = "Komodo Dragon"; //animals stored
        animals[1] = "Manatee";
        animals[2] = "Kakapo";
        animals[3] = "Florida Panther";
        animals[4] = "White Rhino";

        return information;
    }

    public static void forloop()
    {
        String[] animals = new String[5];

        //for loop to print the below print 5 times using the different animal names.
        for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {
            System.out.println(
                    animals[0] + ": How many are left in the wild?");
        }
    }
}
```

2.I want this to print 5 times with the animal name before the question.

Comment: Because you don't execute any code which prints anything. You need to call `forloop()` somewhere.

Comment: 1) Call `forloop()` somewhere, as mentioned. 2) When that doesn't work as expected, be sure to inspect the for loop for any potential off-by-one errors. 3) Always give classes a capital camel-case name (IE: `MyArrays` vs. `arrays`). 4) What is the point of `information`?

Comment: And you need to add `i` in `animals` array to traverse its all elements as `System.out.println(animals[i] + ": How many are left in the wild?");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call your method "forloop()", that's the reason why there's nothing printed.

NewbieJavaDeveloper's answer is a good one. But if you want to pactice "method and return", here is another answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import scanner so user can input

class arrays
{

    public static void main(String[] param)
    {
        String[] animals = arrays();
        forloop(animals);
        System.exit(0);
    } //end main method

    public static String[] arrays() //array method 
    {
        String[] animals = new String[5]; //array to store 5 animals

        animals[0] = "Komodo Dragon"; //animals stored
        animals[1] = "Manatee";
        animals[2] = "Kakapo";
        animals[3] = "Florida Panther";
        animals[4] = "White Rhino";

        return animals;
    }

    public static void forloop(String[] animals)
    {

        for(int i =0; i<5; i++) //for loop to print the below 
        //print 5 times using the different animal names.
        {
            System.out.println(animals[i] + ": How many are left in the wild?");
        }
    }

}
```

I made minimun change to your code, hope you can find it easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this :

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        array();
        //System.exit(0); //not needed
    }

    public static void array()
    {
        String[] animals = new String[5]; //array to store 5 animals

        animals[0] = "Komodo Dragon"; //animals stored
        animals[1] = "Manatee";
        animals[2] = "Kakapo";
        animals[3] = "Florida Panther";
        animals[4] = "White Rhino";

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    animals[i] + ": How many are left in the wild?");
        }
    }    
}
```

**Output:**

```
Komodo Dragon: How many are left in the wild?
Manatee: How many are left in the wild?
Kakapo: How many are left in the wild?
Florida Panther: How many are left in the wild?
White Rhino: How many are left in the wild?
```

Hope it helps,

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: They won't learn if the internet does their homework for them.